# How to make the color fixed after pressing the button and when you return to the application remains for the same color in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

This my code when I press the button will convert the color from green to red and I need it always be red color after I pressed.

```
bool press = false
            Flexible(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: screen.width * 0.01),
                        child: DefaultButton(
                          text: 'Submit Order',
                          press: () {
                            if (enabled == false) {
                              enabled = true;
                              setState(() {
                                press = !press;
                                pressText = !pressText;
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          color: press
                              ? Colors.redAccent
                              : Colors.greenAccent[400],
                        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code already does what you asked for.

Since it cannot be understood from your code snippet about the purpose of `enabled`, I would say to check its value again when you press the button. For example, when you press, the color may not change because `enabled` is `true` at the moment.

But if your question is about persisting the color even after **killing the app**, then I would suggest you to have a look at [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). You can store the required color on press and pick up from this value thereafter.

But if you meant to have the color fixed after first press and no changes there after for any further presses then just set your state like this in press:

```
press: () {
   if (enabled == false) {
     enabled = true;
     setState(() {
       press = true;
       pressText = !pressText;
     });
   }
},
```